# Does the device I'm looking for exist?

Tags: audio, mixer, usb, interface

I'm looking for a simple USB interface that would provide multiple 3.5mm jack audio inputs to my computer.

I've been searching on the web but all I can find is too complicated, with professional connectors and many features I don't need.

I would like something like [this](https://www.digitec.ch/fr/s1/product/logilink-sound-box-71-usb-20-cartes-son-12718793?gclid=CjwKCAiAr6-ABhAfEiwADO4sfeEfqE-jiHWI9LUsTDElbUl4kdlkc9WfUm8ceq_h2sV702NYkSB0BRoCjk4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), but with inputs instead of outputs.

When I came across [this](https://www.wish.com/product/5af886b57af1c2449c63810c?hide_login_modal=true&from_ad=goog_shopping&_display_country_code=CH&_force_currency_code=CHF&pid=googleadwords_int&c=%7BcampaignId%7D&ad_cid=5af886b57af1c2449c63810c&ad_cc=CH&ad_lang=DE&ad_curr=CHF&ad_price=21.00&campaign_id=9527731137&exclude_install=true&gclid=CjwKCAiAr6-ABhAfEiwADO4sfd6Hwtvka9LIWV2gwWhzyIQLn1whLodzi9DiZ15F9ogyQjgCWvJHCRoCWIYQAvD_BwE&share=web), I first thought it was good (excluding the jack size), but the problem here is that it just outputs audio, I want to manage my channels on my computer, as separated tracks in my sequencer (Ableton Live), that I could record separately.

The nearest I found is [this](https://www.esi-audio.com/products/maya44usb/), but unfortunately, it is RCA, not jack...

I thought about a more creative solution, but it doesn't seem very robust: get 4 of [these](https://www.digitec.ch/fr/s1/product/manhattan-adaptateur-audio-3d-usb-a-haut-debit-usb-20-cartes-son-2402480), and put them together using a [USB hub](https://www.digitec.ch/fr/s1/product/equip-usb-hub-4ports-hubs-usb-13274594). Would that work?

In all this I'm a bit surprised not to find... Is my need so odd for such a device to exist?

What do you think?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: You missed to give som important information: how may inputs minimum and what you expect to connect. The requirements are different for a mic requiring plug-in-power as compared to the line out from some device. And by simple I guess you really mean "not expensive", but with cheap often comes lower quality so where you want to go there is important as well.

Comment: Thanks @ghellquist for your feedack. Yes, good point. I was thinking of at least 4 stereo inputs. The goal is to connect small "toy" sequencers. I have several [Teenage Engineering's POs](https://teenage.engineering/products/po) and [Korg Volca synths](https://www.korg.com/us/products/dj/volca_beats/index.php).
What I mean by simple is that I don't need volume knobs, filters, XLR, MIDI, outputs etc... but yes, it comes with cheapness.

Comment: 4 x stereo = 8 channels. Maybe this one, Behringer umc1820. https://www.thomann.de/se/behringer_umc1820.htm . But will you actually use all 4 stereo units at the same time? Maybe one at a time, and then stereo would be Ok.

Comment: Oh, I thought these inputs were stereo.
Yes, at best I would like to use 4 units at the same time, recording live and be able to adapt each track afterwards. This, again, is anoying because my devices produce stereo on the 3.5mm jack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pro (or even semi-pro) audio just doesn't use 3.5mm jacks. It uses quarter inch (or balanced XLR).
You can buy adaptors. Avoid anything that uses RCA or 3.5mm, that's going to be entirely consumer-level.

There are a myriad semi- to pro-level USB audio interfaces available - you just need to search in the right place.
Start at one of the big music shop box shifters like Thomann EU or Sweetwater US (you don't need to buy from there but they have the largest selection to choose from.)

For example - [Thomann](https://www.thomann.de/gb/usb_audiointerfaces.html?sw=usb%20interface&smuuid=b72b0ddb-7eee-4b67-9bb2-9508c233f050)
Pick the number of required i/o channels in the selector on the left to narrow down your search.

BTW, avoid things like that Manhattan adaptor like the plague. They're for consumer headsets.

Comment: Many thanks!
I understand that 3.5mm is not pro. I was not looking for pro equipment. The thing is that my devices are all 3.5mm (see response to ghellquist).
So, I will accept that I will need to buy adaptators with my next purchase.
Thanks for the Thomann link, I already search in there but without that precise filter feature. So, I think maybe [this one](https://www.thomann.de/gb/behringer_umc404hd.htm), or [this other one](https://www.thomann.de/intl/behringer_xenyx_q802_usb.htm), plus extra adaptators, will do the work...
In all cases I have the response to my answer: no.

Comment: *the answer to my question...

Comment: The Behringer stuff is entry-level but seems to be serviceable. I've never really used any of their kit, but enough people seem to like it. Adaptors/splitters are pretty cheap.