# What is happening in my audio interface?

Tags: audio-recording, usb, interface, issue, bad

Following [this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/50298/does-the-device-im-looking-for-exist), I acquired a second hand [Behringer U-Phoria UMC404HD](https://www.behringer.com/product.html?modelCode=P0BK1) audio interface.

I'm suprised to find out that it seems to totally distort, or apply filter to my audio input.
To better explain the distortion, I shot a little demo video, with the same audio, first passing directly to my recorder, then passing through the Behringer device: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gkcfXRrsWcWwwyoDWwsJYNY90_eDxP8a/view?usp=sharing

PS1: I've tried all 4 inputs, different cables, different jack adaptors. I've tried output to headphones, main output and USB to my laptop. I've tried all knobs and switches. The audio is always bad.
PS2: The song is Tangerine by Glass Animals

Comment: Looks like you're feeding some king of headphone/mic combo output to a single mono input. i can't figure why you'd even want to feed a computer out to a preamp that way, even if cabled correctly. Why no use the pre as it's designed & use its actual outputs? From your earlier question… "I'm looking for a simple USB interface that would provide multiple 3.5mm jack audio inputs to my computer." …but that's not what you've done.

Comment: BTW, I hear no distortion, just simple phase cancellation, which has the effect of removing the centre of the image & anything placed there, like the drum track.

Comment: The configuration I set in the video is just for the demo, I have no interest using my computer as audio source. What I want is plug multiple pocket operator units and record them in my sequencer via USB. That works but the audio is awful...

Comment: Okay, is that normal that the interface applies that kind of filter ? I just want raw input...

Comment: It's not applying any kind of "filter" you've stuffed a stereo jack into a mono input & it's shorting out. That's really not the way to route it at all. Read the manual - if you want to route the outputs, use the outputs, not the inputs. I can't see from your video what it is you're trying to do at all… compy stereo out to mono in, then a headphone out to what looks like a Zoom, then out again to speakers!?! That makes zero sense.

Comment: I know the setup in the video makes no sense, I just needed an audio input to illustrate my issue. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b_Zeke6zmxjVpVQrE1VXkfYZeJlFsEW5/view?usp=sharing) is a picture of the real configuration I want to use.
Thank you, now I understand that I can't enter stereo into these mono inputs. What should I do since my devices produces stereo ?
About the manual, [here](https://mediadl.musictribe.com/media/sys_master/h7e/hfb/8849567252510.pdf) is the manual, and I read it before coming here but didn't learn much...

Comment: Each stereo out needs to be split to two separate mono ins, then panned left & right. You don't have enough inputs for three stereo devices.

Comment: I see...
I think the left and right channels from my devices are same, so I could separate L/R and plug only one in my input, this way I could still use 4 devices at a time.
Do you think [this kind of splitter](https://www.gear4music.com/Books-DVD-and-Sheet-Music/Hosa-YMP-137-Stereo-Breakout-Cable-35mm-TRS-to-Dual-1-4-TSF/L1L) could do the trick ?

Comment: You need to read the spec sheet/manual for your devices to know the pinout & whether or not they're mono or stereo. The splitter might work if they are mono. I really can't help any further. You need to read up about your equipment, learn it & understand it, rather than ask question after question. This is not a product helpline, sorry, it's a sound design QA site. Your question as it started is barely on-topic, it's now devolved into "live chat".

Comment: I see StackExchange as a way to help each other (and yes, to shortcut official literature). And you helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tetsujin, I have the answer to my question: There is nothing wrong with my audio interface. I just had an inapporiate use of it.

The issue was caused by the audio source being stereo coming into a mono input.

For what I understood (but I sure am no expert), the input connector beeing a XLR/jack combo, is balanced. So it excpects the right signal from the cable to be the inverse of the left signal. As I enter stereo with similar L and R, the result was sort of a cancelation of the signal.
*Edit: by left and right I mean "tip" and "ring" of the connector, which are used as positive and negative polarity for balanced mono signal ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Design)).*

The next step for me is finding some kind of stereo to mono splitters in order to plug my Pocket Operators properly.

Comment: To be very clear. The XLR cable as well as the 1/4 inch jack receives one mono signal. A stereo output is two mono channels so cannot come in through one XLR or one jack.  (Note: the specific interface the user is talking about, we know that a 1/4 inch jack can be used for stereo, eg as headphone).

Comment: Thanks @ghellquist. Sorry I don't have the correct vocabulary, I editet my answer. There is no left and right signals but one signal being splitted into positive and negative polarity.